# Want to rename all keys names in loop

Tags: arrays, json, xml, parsing, key

I have a json format. Now i want to replace all the **p:** from my json and covert into real name like p:OrderId to OrderId, p:Firstname to Firstname.

Please check below JSON.

> {"status":"success","msg":{"$":{"xmlns:p":"342","xmlns:xsi":"test
>   link","xsi:schemaLocation":"324","source":"234234"},"p:Customer":[{"p:OrderId":["asdasd"],"p:FirstName":["Ingrid"],"p:LastName":["Bryne"],"p:EmailAddress":["asd@ad.com"],"p:BirthDate":["1965-09-23"],"p:CellularPhone":["123465798"],"p:City":["asd"],"p:Country":["asdda"],"p:PostalCode":["23332"],"p:StreetAddress":["asd"],"p:PartnerId":["1-84OPG"],"p:CommunicationPreferences":[{"p:Phone":["12"],"p:Email":["123"],"p:Mail":["231"],"p:SMS":["Nei"]}],"p:ServiceAgreement":[{"p:AgreementType":["Bredbånd
>   - Privat"],"p:AgreementStartDate":["123"],"p:AgreementStatus":["ASS"],"p:Comment":["\n\nse.
>   \n\n"],"p:ListOfAssets":[{"p:Asset":[{"p:ProductPartNumber":["234"],"p:Comments":[""]},{"p:ProductPartNumber":["123"],"p:Comments":[""]},{"p:ProductPartNumber":["12313"],"p:Comments":[""]},{"p:ProductPartNumber":["123"],"p:Comments":[""]},{"p:ProductPartNumber":["123"],"p:Comments":[""]},{"p:ProductPartNumber":["123123"],"p:Comments":[""]}]}]}]}]}}

Output : https://prnt.sc/hwc157

Note : I have convert my real values to demo values. I need to change Key names with values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code:

```js
var jsn = '{"status":"success","msg":{"$":{"xmlns:p":"342","xmlns:xsi":"test link","xsi:schemaLocation":"324","source":"234234"},"p:Customer":[{"p:OrderId":["asdasd"],"p:FirstName":["Ingrid"],"p:LastName":["Bryne"],"p:EmailAddress":["asd@ad.com"],"p:BirthDate":["1965-09-23"],"p:CellularPhone":["123465798"],"p:City":["asd"],"p:Country":["asdda"],"p:PostalCode":["23332"],"p:StreetAddress":["asd"],"p:PartnerId":["1-84OPG"],"p:CommunicationPreferences":[{"p:Phone":["12"],"p:Email":["123"],"p:Mail":["231"],"p:SMS":["Nei"]}],"p:ServiceAgreement":[{"p:AgreementType":["Bredbånd - Privat"],"p:AgreementStartDate":["123"],"p:AgreementStatus":["ASS"],"p:Comment":["se."],"p:ListOfAssets":[{"p:Asset":[{"p:ProductPartNumber":["234"],"p:Comments":[""]},{"p:ProductPartNumber":["123"],"p:Comments":[""]},{"p:ProductPartNumber":["12313"],"p:Comments":[""]},{"p:ProductPartNumber":["123"],"p:Comments":[""]},{"p:ProductPartNumber":["123"],"p:Comments":[""]},{"p:ProductPartNumber":["123123"],"p:Comments":[""]}]}]}]}]}}';

 var ret = jsn.replace(/p:/g,'');
 var obj = JSON.parse(ret);
 console.log(obj);
```